# How can I get VSCode to pull the correct type imports for ReactNode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm getting a red underline in VSCode with the following error message. All I'm trying to do is add a custom JSX element (ReactGridLayout) to a JSX div. It appears somewhere I'm getting two mismatched versions of React types for "ReactNode". Not sure what could be causing this, but any help would be much appreciated. Code does appear to compile fine, so I think it's just a VSCode issue. Just trying to get this annoying red underline to go away / resolve the two types correctly. Note that "react-grid-layout" is just a popular open source library.

```
'ReactGridLayout' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'Responsive' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'import("/Users/ac/Dev/vfinal-web/node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'React.ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

Image of the output is as follows:

[image: VSCode Error]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) I was going to attempt to recreate this in a typescript playground, but I'm not gonna type all that from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Yarn workspaces** the reason for your error might be that `react-grid-layout` does not provide a peer dependency for `react`. I had a similar issue with `react-rnd` (see [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/4371) for further details)

You can fix this by adding:

```
packageExtensions:
  'react-grid-layout@*':
    peerDependencies:
      'react': '*'
```

to your `.yarnrc.yml`.

Comment: Thanks - thought this solved it, but unfortunately didn't. Has to be something along these lines though... So odd for it to pick a relative ref when React is at top level.

Comment: Just checked your image and have seen that the closing tag of `ReacGridLayout` does not wrap `with=…`